# HTML multiple image tags with same image only showing one image instead of same image many times

Tags: html, image

I have some HTML code with a animating GIF as placeholder to show while the browser is waiting for data like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> Total Units</span>
    <div id="total_units_content" class="count" >
        <img border="0" id="avatar-green" alt="avatar-green" src="~/images/avatar-green.gif" width=50" height="50">
    </div>
    <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">0% </i> From last Week </span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
    <span class="count_top">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Total units online
    </span>
    <div id="total_units_online_content" class="count" >
        <img border="0" id="avatar-green" alt="avatar-green" src="~/images/avatar-green.gif" width=50" height="50">
    </div>
    <span class="count_bottom">
        <i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>0% </i> From last Week
    </span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
    <span class="count_top">
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Total units offline
    </span>
    <div id="total_units_offline_content" class="count green">
        <img border="0" alt="avatar-green" src="~/images/avatar-green.gif" width=50" height="50">
    </div>
    <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">
        <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>0% </i> From last Week
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem is that only the first image is showing, and I only get the alt text for the other images.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your image tags are missing a `"` on `width=50"`. Correct to `width="50"`.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks that was the problem.